# Easiest way to get URL from a SVN checkout

Tags: svn

I can get it by parsing the output of `svn info`. Example using Bash:

```
svn info | grep '^URL: ' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
svn info | awk '/^URL: / { print $2 }'
```

There's also `svn info --xml` if you'd rather parse XML.

There's no command line parameter that returns *only* the URL, if that's what you meant.

Comment: Yup, that´s what I meant.